# SQL Server - using LAG in SUM of calculated field

Tags: sql-server

I have a need to calculate a running total based on the value of a field in a different column in a preceding row.

A simplified example would be

e.g.

```
Day Investment(A)  Payments(B)   Multiplier(C) Profit(D)  TotalFund(E)
0   100            0                0             0         100
1   100            0                0.1           10        110
2   100            0                0.5           55        165
3   90            10               -0.2          -33        122
4   70            20                0.5           61        163
5   80           -10                0.1           16.3      189.3
```

So my table will contain columns Day, Investment(A), Payments(B) and Multiplier(C).
Profit(D) is calculated as TotalFund(E) from previous day multiplied by Multiplier(C) for the current day
TotalFund(E) is calculated as TotalFund(E) from previous day plus Profit(D) from current day minus Payments(B) from current day

I can't figure out how I can do this using LAG within a SUM

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: 1st TotalFund(E) should not be 0 ? How its 100?

Comment: First info you should give:  Which dbms you are using!!!!!!

Comment: You know... It stands to reason that someone not familiar enough with SE might also not be particularly familiar with the acronym "DBMS"

Comment: Sorry this is for SQL Server 2012

Comment: Day 0 is just there to show that the initial investment is 100.  Day 1 is where you calculate the profit and the total fund

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can calculate it with `LAG`. Here is a solution using `recursive CTE`

```
with myTable as (
    select * from
        (values 
            (0,100,0,0)
            ,(1,100,0,0.1)
            ,(2,100,0,0.5)
            ,(3,90,10,-0.2)
            ,(4,70,20,0.5)
            ,(5,80,-10,0.1)
        ) t ([Day], [Investment(A)], [Payments(B)], [Multiplier(C)])
)
, rcte as (
    select
        *, [Profit(D)] = cast(0 as decimal(20,4)), [TotalFund(E)] = cast(100 as decimal(20,4))
    from
        myTable
    where [Day] = 0

    union all

    select
        b.[Day], b.[Investment(A)], b.[Payments(B)], b.[Multiplier(C)], cast(a.[TotalFund(E)] * b.[Multiplier(C)] as decimal(20,4))
        , cast(a.[TotalFund(E)] + a.[TotalFund(E)] * b.[Multiplier(C)] - b.[Payments(B)] as decimal(20,4))
    from
        rcte a
        join myTable b on a.[Day] + 1 = b.[Day]
)

select * from rcte

option (maxrecursion 0)
```